# What's wrong with my spinner?

Tags: android

I am developing an application where I use spinner:

```
    s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    s2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp2);
    s3=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sp3);


    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();



    for (int i=1;i<=31;i++)
   {
       list1.add(i);
   }

    for (int i=1;i<=12;i++)
    {
        list2.add(i);
    }
    for (int i=1917;i<=2017;i++)
    {
        list3.add(i);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list2);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> dataAdapter3 = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list3);
    dataAdapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dataAdapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    s1.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
    s2.setAdapter(dataAdapter2);
    s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter3);



    final int day = (Integer)s1.getSelectedItem();
    final int month =(Integer)s2.getSelectedItem() ;
    final int year = (Integer)s3.getSelectedItem();
```

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">



 <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Identifiant"
    android:layout_weight="0.05" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ed1"
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="193dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Mot de passe"

    android:layout_weight="0.06" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed2"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />

   </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="192dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Confirmer mot de passe"

    android:layout_weight="0.06" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed3"
        android:layout_width="193dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />
 </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date de naissance"
        android:layout_weight="0.06" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>



<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:text="Valider" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

but when I print the year for example, it does not print the item I actually chose (it prints 2017). What should I do? Am I doing wrong with spinner methods? Thanks in advance

Comment: change de variable numbers in the 3 last lines: it should be s1 - s2 - s3

Answer (score 0):

A guess, this:

```
final int day = (Integer)s1.getSelectedItem();
final int month =(Integer)s1.getSelectedItem() ;
final int year = (Integer)s1.getSelectedItem();
```

should be:

```
final int day = (Integer)s1.getSelectedItem();
final int month =(Integer)s2.getSelectedItem() ;
final int year = (Integer)s3.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Actually it prints 1917 whatever year I choose

Answer (score 0):

```
final int day = (Integer) s1.getSelectedItem();
final int month =(Integer) s2.getSelectedItem() ;
final int year = (Integer) s3.getSelectedItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

s1,s2 and s3 are three different spinners . But you are trying to get their selected values using s1 itself . So ,for getting year you should use s3 .

Comment: It prints 1917 whatever year I choose

Answer (score 0):

avoid copy paste.
it should be :

final int day = (Integer)***s1***.getSelectedItem();

final int month =(Integer)***s2***.getSelectedItem() ;

final int year = (Integer)***s3***.getSelectedItem();